# screen blinks during activity starts in android

Tags: android

I have redirecting the fragment to activity.Progress wheel rotate before getting the data and then it will stops after getting data from web service.After loading the data from web service the screen gets blinks fraction of seconds.After blinking all the data are displayed in activity.How to remove the blinking effects in android?
`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
        fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content));

        SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        userID= prefs1.getString("userid", null);
        System.out.println("userid" + userID);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        useridpost = i.getStringExtra("postuserid");
        subuser=i.getStringExtra("subuserid");

        btnBack=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button_back);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(checking){
                    Intent cancel = new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    cancel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    cancel.putExtra("testedit", "testedit");
                    startActivity(cancel);
                }
                else{
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
        emptyView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

        if(subuser!=null){
            if(subuser.equals(userID)){
                emptyView.setText("No Posts for you");
            }
            else{
                emptyView.setText("No Posts to show");
            }
        }

        if(useridpost==null) {
            // editor.putString("useridfromprofile", userID);
            userID = prefs1.getString("userid", null);
            System.out.println("user id from shared preferences"+userID);
        }
        else
        {
            userID=useridpost;
            System.out.println("user id from arguments"+userID);
        }

        pw=(ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.pw_spinner);
        obj.styleRandom(pw,getApplicationContext());

        recyclerView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter=new CustomPostAdapter1(this,feedsList,PostActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        getProfilePosts();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

On the exiting `activity`, call `getWindow().setExitTransition(null);`
On the entering `activity`, call `getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);`

It will prevent the fade out of the exiting `activity` and the fade in of the entering `activity`, which removes the apparent blinking effect.

Comment: i have tried already but it shows error like this 
 Call requires API level 21 (current min is 16) in setEnterTransition(null);place what to do for rectifying this error?

Comment: Anyone give solution soon plz